# How do I get my stored procedure to work?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL to create a stored procedure that will do a search with varied search filters. I have been reading multiple things on how to get this task done, and while it seems to work for every single person that has used their stored procedure, I cannot figure out why it doesn't work when I do it. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Create Procedure spSearchInventory
@SKU int(25),
@ItemName varchar(40),
@RetailPrice decimal(7,2),
@WholesalePrice decimal(7,2),
@DateOfPurchase date,
@DateOfPost date
As
Begin

    SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE
    (SKU = @SKU OR @SKU IS NULL) AND
    (ItemName = @ItemName OR @ItemName IS NULL) AND
    (RetailPrice = @RetailPrice OR @RetailPrice IS NULL) AND
    (WholesalePrice = @WholesalePrice OR @WholesalePrice IS NULL) AND
    (DateOfPurchase = @DateOfPurchase OR @DateOfPurchase IS NULL) AND
    (DateOfPost = @DateOfPost OR @DateOfPost IS NULL)
END
```

The error it gives me is right at the top  "@SKU int (25)". The error it reads is, "Syntax Error: '@SKU' (at text suffix) is not a valid input at this position. I am new to SQL, so this may be a simple issue, however, this is the exact same stored procedure that others have used, and gotten success from, so I'm not sure why it won't work when I try to do it.

Comment: Declare variables in SQL with DECLARE. Int also takes no argument as it is a static type. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: You have a length defined for int when you should not. just change "@SKU int(25)," to "@SKU int,"

Comment: tried both of these and it still tells me that's not correct. I'm really getting frustrated with this, because I cannot figure out how to get ANY stored procedure to work. Even simple ones.

Answer (score 1):

Brandon,
you are using SQL Server syntax in your procedure. To use MySQL syntax:

```
create procedure spSearchInventory (
in_SKU int,
in_ItemName varchar(40),
in_RetailPrice decimal(7,2),
in_WholesalePrice decimal(7,2),
in_DateOfPurchase date,
in_DateOfPost date
)
begin

SELECT * 
FROM inventory 
WHERE 
    (SKU = in_SKU OR in_SKU IS NULL) AND
    (ItemName = in_ItemName OR in_ItemName IS NULL) AND
    (RetailPrice = in_RetailPrice OR in_RetailPrice IS NULL) AND
    (WholesalePrice = in_WholesalePrice OR in_WholesalePrice IS NULL) AND
    (DateOfPurchase = in_DateOfPurchase OR in_DateOfPurchase IS NULL) AND
    (DateOfPost = in_DateOfPost OR in_DateOfPost IS NULL);

END
```

Comment: I didn't realize there was a different syntax. I assumed it was universal. You can clearly tell how new I am to all of this. Thanks a lot!